# VBA Shared Functions between addins?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, excel-addins, code-duplication

I currently have a single .xlam addin deployed and version controlled, and have been asked to split this into several separate code bases to version controlled and deployed separately.

Can Addin 'A' reference a function in Addin 'B' , or would I replicate the function in each?

I was thinking about loading in the vba from .bas files dynamically at runtime - however this still duplicates code all over the place.

Comment: `Can Addin 'A' reference a function in Addin 'B'`: Yes. Ensure Add-ins have a project name. You may also want to see [THIS](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut08.htm)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about name projects - I'll post back here with results when I get it working so it helps someone else. It's hard to know with so many old threads knocking around on the internet, how relevant some of the excel stuff is for Office 365.  On the flip side, much of VBA  hasn't changed since the early 2000's :)